# float to binary <-> binary to float conversion

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to convert a float number to a binary string and back.

I tried this:

```
import struct
from ast import literal_eval


float_to_binary = bin(struct.unpack('!i',struct.pack('!f', 3.14))[0])
print (float_to_binary)

binary_to_float = float(int(float_to_binary, 0))
print (binary_to_float)


result = float(literal_eval(float_to_binary))
print (result) #wrong, prints 1078523331.0, should be 3.14
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't do what you think:

```
binary_to_float = float(int(float_to_binary, 0))
```

it doesn't reinterpret the data, rather it converts integer to float, e.g. `1234` to `1234.0`.

you can use:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>>
>>> # float -> binary
>>> bin( unpack('I', pack('f', 3.14))[0] )
'0b1000000010010001111010111000011'
>>>
>>>
>>> # binary -> float
>>> unpack('f', pack('I', 0b1000000010010001111010111000011) )[0]
(3.140000104904175,)
>>>
```

Comment: cool, though when I use variables, like this:

original_float = 3.14

binary_string = int(bin( unpack('I', pack('f', original_float))[0] ))

float_value = unpack('f', pack('I', binary_string) )[0]

doesn't work. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b1000000010010001111010111000011'

Comment: @omgzor You need to tell `int` that the integer in the string is integer of base 2 using `int(..., 2)`, so it should be `binary_string = int(bin( unpack('I', pack('f', original_float))[0] ), 2)`. You can remove `int(bin(...), 2)` if you are just interested in the base 10 value, `binary_string = unpack('I', pack('f', original_float))[0]`.

Comment: I don't think this works, not exactly.  int is 32 bit and float is 64 bit.